# Combining borders after showing data

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, border

I am attempting to combine a border for a title and description. The title shows upon page load, but once the title is clicked its description appears below it in its own border. I want those borders to combine when the description is showing.

I created a snipet to show what I have so far.

```js
$('.service_wrapper').click(function() {
   var thisDescription = $('.service_description', $(this));

   // Hide all other descriptions
   $('.service_description').not(thisDescription).hide();

   // Toggle (show or hide) this description
   thisDescription.toggle(500);
 });
```

```css
.service_list {
 margin-left: 20%;
} 
.service_title {
 border: 1px solid black;
 padding: 8px;
 width: 20%;
 margin: 15px 0;
}
.service_title:hover {
 background-color: gray;
 color: blue;
 cursor: pointer;
}
.service_description { 
 display: none;
 border: 1px solid black;
 padding: 8px;
 width: 20%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="service_list">
 <div class="service_wrapper">
   <div class="service_title">Floors</div>
   <div class="service_description">The best floors!</div>
 </div>
 <div class="service_wrapper">
   <div class="service_title">Roofs</div>
   <div class="service_description">Your roof will be perfect!</div>
 </div>
 <div class="service_wrapper">
   <div class="service_title">Siding</div>
   <div class="service_description">mmmm siding.</div>
 </div>
 <div class="service_wrapper">
   <div class="service_title">Paint</div>
   <div class="service_description">Fabulous paint!</div>
 </div>
 <div class="service_wrapper">
   <div class="service_title">Kitchen Remodels</div>
   <div class="service_description">Pretty kitchen.</div>
 </div>
</div>
```

I am trying to make it do something like this:

http://royalwoodfloor.com/services/

Does anyone know what I should do?

Image

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just change your css like this

```
        .service_title {
            border: 1px solid black;
            padding: 8px;
            width: 20%;
            margin: 15px 0 0 0;/* update the margin */
        }
```

here is the example link [the example link](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/yeVXXa)

Updated the code snipet

Comment: Then I wouldn't have any margin under each service_title.

Comment: If yo want combine border just add this css `box-sizing: border-box`

Comment: have you tried? you have margin top 15px, it looks the same as your example. check the example [the example](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/yeVXXa)

Comment: Ok cool. How would I take away the bottom service/top description border when it has been expanded though?

Comment: if you can share an image to understand what you want, maybe i can help better.

Comment: That snippet you added is what my code was doing before. I added a picture of the page I was referring to in my question. As you can see where my arrows are the border goes away there when expanded. If you would like to see it working, go to this site: http://royalwoodfloor.com/services/

Comment: Now i seee what you want, i updated the code snipet http://codepen.io/anon/pen/yeVXXa

Comment: What did you do? Also do you know why when you click outside the box, the descriptions show? If you click anywhere to the right of any service title it toggles it.

Comment: Hahaha, It is because your target is `$('.service_wrapper')...` and it is wrapping all the elements, it means when you click at any element inside it clicking the `.service_wrapper` too, if you only whant open the description when the title is clicked, you need update your Js, something like this `title.click, if this cousin description is close open it, if not, close it`

Comment: I just tried adding a width of 20% to the service wrapper as well, but that still allows clicking outside of the box. What would you recommend?

Comment: Never mind, it seems like when I changed some of my css to what you had, it fixed it.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/99226/discussion-between-roll-and-becky).

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this. Slightly changed your HTML structure and css.

HTML

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="service_list">
    <div class="service_wrapper">
  <div class="service_title"><span>Floors</span>
  <div class="service_description"><span>The best floors!</span></div>
    </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.service_list {
    margin-left: 20%;
}   
.service_title {
    border: 1px solid black;

    width: 30%;

}
.service_title span{
  padding:8px 8px 8px 8px;
 display:inline-block;
}
.service_title:hover {
    background-color: gray;
    color: blue;
    cursor: pointer;
}
.service_description { 
    display: none;
    border-top: 1px solid black;
}
.service_description span{
  padding:10px

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Separate from the animation transition not being the same as the example, this fixes the margin issue:

```
    .service_description { 
        display: none;
        border: 1px solid black;
        padding: 8px;
        width: 20%;
        margin-top: -16px;
    }
```

See it working [**here**](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/XXNgNR)

Comment: How can I get service_title's /service_description's bottom border to go away when it expands?

Comment: I changed the animation from toggle to slideToggle a little bit ago.

Comment: You want the border for both to go away when the description appears or just the service-title?

Comment: Just like in that example. Where the title's bottom border goes away and then description only has the right, bottom and left border.